# How to get around the text limitations of a TextView element?

Tags: android, textview

Apparently there seems to be a text length limit on the TextView element when used within a ListView. I have to admit I have not checked the actual limit that I am facing, but it is clear to me that 2k characters is no biggie, where 4k characters is simply not being displayed.
And "not displayed" is not even right, as the screen seems to be scrollable for the full length of the TextView (although all I get to see is whitespace).

My issue: I am displaying a ListView for an email message. All parts of the mail are in seperate TextView elements that get dropped into the ListView.
When a lengthy message (somewhere above 2k characters) is put into a TextView, the TextView remains empty but does occupy space.

My question: What alternatives/options are there to make this problem go away?
Eg Making the entire message displayable (even long ones).

Thanks to anyone in advance for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you have to use a ListView? It seems like you'd be better served with a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView, or maybe just put the body of the email inside a ScrollView if you want to keep the other TextViews on the screen.

If you want to stick with the ListView, you might consider using String#substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) to ellipsize the body and show the full body in another Activity launched in the onListItemClick handler for the list view. You can use the android:ellipsize property in your XML layout (or TextView#setEllipsize in Java code) to limit the text to a single line, but that is probably not what you want.

Comment: The reason to use a listView, is because the entire application consists of information flattened using ListViews. Building all the screens by hand is going to be extremely cumborsome. Hence I wrote a very cool looking ListAdapter that fits my exact needs. Each row can have several types of displayable information. In this case, the message is simply displayed as is in the TextView (which is wrapped in a LinearLayout lol)

Comment: BTW, I am going to keep your hint, as it will probably happen anyways. I have been facing several severe shortcomings on the ListView, and your suggestion is probably the best to get rid of all of that :))

Answer (score 0):

you can set the singleLine property to true so that only the text visible in single line can be shown on listview or in addition set the maxline property to 1

Comment: That's not an option. I need the message to be displayed as is, wether it be a long or short message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `android:maxLength` property for TextView element in xml
or
to set filter `new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxlength)`?

Comment: This is exacly what I am currently doing so text will at least show up. In code, I check if the text is too long, cut of a part from the end so I can inform the user that the text is too long.

Comment: What kind of Adapter you're using?

Comment: A simple extension of BaseAdapter :)

Comment: I have created ListView with TextView elements containing 10k characters each. It works. Android 2.2 HTC Desire. Do you have only TextView in rows?

Comment: Unfortunatly not. The rows can have several different layouts. This specific one is one of many :(

Comment: You must've done an error in adapter or layout. Open hierarchyviewer to check if TextView is visible on screen or is somewhere outside. Check adapter if it creates/updates views properly. Or paste more code to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason for this quirk!
This is a BUG that exists in Android < 2.2 !

After dziobas pointed out that he filled 10k char strings on 2.2, I tried this out on a new emulator image.
I am still going to change my code in the end to not use the ListView and reimplement my own ListView like class as Brian suggested